# res.writeHead and res.end in different scopes gives error

Tags: node.js

Below is my code:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(testfunc)
.listen(3333);
function testfunc(req,res) {
                    
    if (req.method === 'GET'){

        fs.readFile('index.html', function(err,data){
            
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.write(data);
            res.write("Hi");
            
        
        });
        res.end();
    
    };
};
```

I am getting error as below when I send get request to /. Can you let me know what is the issue. If remove res.end() is working fine. But what's wrong in writing res.end().

> events.js:292
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
>
> Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
> at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:629:17)
> at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:621:15)
> at C:\Users\C5218529\3D Objects\RestApi\node-shop-sql\server.js:12:8
> at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3) Emitted 'error' event on
> ServerResponse instance at:
> at writeAfterEndNT (_http_outgoing.js:684:7)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21) {   code:
> 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END' }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

res.end(); should be after res.write("Hi"); inside callback function fs.readFile().
Because callback function executes later (res.write) and res.end() is executing first.

We cannot write to response after we call res.end() statement.

Comment: But it is in the scope of createServer callback function itself. And if I remove res.end(); it works perfectly.

Comment: res.end(); --> executes before fs.readFile('index.html', function(err,data){}); callback. You need to keep res.end() in fs.readFile() as it is async call

Comment: Add console.log() statements before res.end() and res.write() you will get to know the execution flow

Answer (score 0):

```
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(err,data){
        // these callback statements will be executed later
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        res.write("Hi");
        res.end();
    
    });
    // statements below will be executed immediately after fs.readFile as it is async
```